# Differentiation of a sum and product with respect to a constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, summation, products

I would like to differentiate the following expression with respect to b:

$$\sum_{i=1}^M (\prod_{j=1}^{i-1} (b+1+a_j))$$
$$a_j\in\mathbb{R}$$
$$b\in\mathbb{R}$$

aj is a small number between between -0.16 and 0.16.
b is constant and is also small between -0.001 and 0.001.
M will be 4000.

It would be helpful to take b out of the product and sum. I also thought about expanding the product and then rewriting the expanded product as a sum. Seems difficult. How should I go about differentiating this expression with respect to b?

Answer (score 0):

If $D$ is derivative with respect to $b$ and $E$ is that expression, then

$$
DE=\sum_{i=0}^MD\prod_{j-1}^{i-1}(b+1+a_j)
$$

Then you are apply [Leibniz's rule for the derivative of a product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule)

$$
DE = \sum_{i=0}^M\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\prod_{k=1, k\neq j}^{i-1}(b+1+a_j)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$y=\sum_{i=1}^M \left(\prod_{j=1}^{i-1} (b+1+a_j)\right)$$ define
$$f_i=\prod_{j=1}^{i-1} (b+1+a_j)\implies y=\sum_{i=1}^M f_i\implies y'=\sum_{i=1}^M f'_i$$
Now
$$\log(f_i)=\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \log(b+1+a_j)\implies \frac{f'_i}{f_i}=\frac 1 {b+1+a_j}\implies f'_i=\frac {f_i} {b+1+a_j}$$